# Web Application download from Azure Storage Blobs to Computer

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, download

I am trying to download files from azure to computer via an web app. It works when I run locally the project, but when uploaded to ftp server it does not download.

I have tried Environment.SpecialFolder.Peronal, Desktop, etc.

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadBlobAsync(string file, string fileExtension, string directory)
    {

        string downlaodPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        _container = _client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        _directoy = _container.GetDirectoryReference(directory);

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _directoy.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(downlaodPath +  "/"+ file + "." + fileExtension))
        {
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

The expected output should be on the documents or desktop.

Comment: If you are hosting the web app on a web server, then it is highly likely that you don't have access to a Desktop or Personal folder.  This would be because the web application is running under a special user account that has restrictions on what it can access with respect to the local machine.  I would be looking to download the blob to a temp folder (there are API's that will help you generate a temp file name that is in a location that the web application will have access to).  Would be worth updating your question with details of what you want to do with the file once it's been downloaded.

Comment: It is to download files they select. For example, there is a file named myimage.png. They can click it and download it.

Comment: The issue i am encountering is that is trying to save to C: instead of the Documents folder.  When I see the errors in the browser that is what is trying to do instead of the path for the documents or downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are seeing is due to the fact that your code is executing **on the webserver**, not on the clients (users) machine.

In other words, when you try to save to `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`, you're trying to save it to that folder on the web server, not the users desktop computer.

What you need to do is return the content of the blob in the request, and let the browser save the file - the user is likely to be prompted (depending on their browser settings) where exactly to save it.  You should not be specifying this.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadBlobAsync(string file, string fileExtension, string directory)
{
    _container = _client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    _directoy = _container.GetDirectoryReference(directory);

    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _directoy.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray())
        };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "somefilename.ext"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(blockBlob.Properties.ContentType);

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Note** that this is inefficient, as it will download the blob first to the webserver, and then return that to the client.  It should be enough to get started.

When this endpoint is hit by the browser, the user will be prompted to save the file somewhere on their PC.

Comment: So i could use a jquery to retrieve the file and allow user to save it.

Question: result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(res.ContentType);

What is the res at the end? I see no variable for it being declared or passed to it

Comment: result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(blockBlob.Properties.ContentType);

I think this is what is going on in that line

Comment: Yes - I've updated the code (I based it off some other stuff that I was using internally).  How you hit this endpoint really depends on how you've built your front end.

Comment: What i did is just made the azure public so I can download the links directly. It made it easier, and since all those files will be available for download anyways, there is no reason for blob to be private.